# Make a store without using Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was trying to understand how to use Vuex, but since I'm pretty new to VueJS world, I didn't understand It well.

So now I'm looking for alternative.

I want to share data between 2 components, so let's say this.

I have view file (component that contain product) and Cart component.So I want to build add to cart feature, and that's why I need some kind of store.

Any idea, advice ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an object.

From the official docs:

```
var sourceOfTruth = {}
var vmA = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})
var vmB = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State-Management

Comment: I'm using a bit more modular way with webpack and . (dot) vue files.
So maybe option should be creare store file with JS object and store data from API to it ? But then what about reactivity ?

Comment: You can't be modular in the business logic.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't catch what you want to say.

Comment: The business logic would preferably be at the same level of abstraction, this means no modularity. In fact you should strive for high-coesion of strongly related functions. In your case coordination between the cart and the product.